# Employee is a namespace but is used like a type

Tags: c#

I have this C# homework when I run the program I get an error that states "Employee is a namespace but is used like type in line 18 which is 'public double salary;'. Problem is I don't see anything wrong. Can someone help me fix this code. Below is the current code I have. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Employee
{
    struct Employees
    {
        public int Worker_ID;
        public string lastname;
        public string firstname;
        public int phone;
        public double salary;
    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<Employees> dataList = new List<Employees>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void GetData(ref Employees info)
        {
            try
            {
                info.Worker_ID = int.Parse(employeebox.Text);
                info.lastname = lastnamebox.Text;
                info.firstname = firstnamebox.Text;
                info.phone = int.Parse(phonebox.Text);
                info.salary = double.Parse(salarybox.Text);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }       

        private void savebt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Employees save = new Employees();
            GetData(ref save);
            dataList.Add(save);

            employeebox.Clear();
            lastnamebox.Clear();
            firstnamebox.Clear();
            phonebox.Clear();
            salarybox.Clear();

            employeebox.Focus();
        }

        private void employeesbt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string output;
            employeelistbox.Items.Clear();
            foreach (Employees aSave in dataList)
            {
                output = aSave.Worker_ID + " " + aSave.lastname + aSave.firstname + "Salary :" + aSave.salary;
                employeelistbox.Items.Add(output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You did not end your namespace `Employee` with closing braces at the end.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Employee
{
struct Employees
{
    public int Worker_ID;
    public string lastname;
    public string firstname;
    public int phone;
    public double salary;
}
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Employees> dataList = new List<Employees>();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void GetData(ref Employees info)
    {
        try
        {
            info.Worker_ID = int.Parse(employeebox.Text);
            info.lastname = lastnamebox.Text;
            info.firstname = firstnamebox.Text;
            info.phone = int.Parse(phonebox.Text);
            info.salary = double.Parse(salarybox.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }       

    private void savebt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     Employees save = new Employees();
        GetData(ref save);
        dataList.Add(save);

        employeebox.Clear();
        lastnamebox.Clear();
        firstnamebox.Clear();
        phonebox.Clear();
        salarybox.Clear();

        employeebox.Focus();
    }

    private void employeesbt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string output;
        employeelistbox.Items.Clear();
        foreach (Employees aSave in dataList)
        {
            output = aSave.Worker_ID + " " + aSave.lastname + aSave.firstname + "Salary :" + aSave.salary;
        employeelistbox.Items.Add(output);
        }
    }


}
} // -> 1 Extra Parenthesis required
```